# Add combobox to account settings screen

Tags: angular, abp

I'm currently working on abp project (latest version) using Angular, so I want to add a combo box to the account section under the Personal Settings tab

[image]

So, I'm reading this [docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Dynamic-Form-Extensions)

It says that I need to create a ts file as:

```
import {
    eIdentityComponents,
    IdentityCreateFormPropContributors,
  } from '@abp/ng.identity';
  import { IdentityUserDto } from '@abp/ng.identity/proxy'
  import { ePropType, FormProp, FormPropList } from '@abp/ng.theme.shared/extensions';
  import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
  
  const timeZoneProp = new FormProp<IdentityUserDto>({
    type: ePropType.Date,
    name: 'timeZone',
    displayName: 'AbpIdentity::TimeZone',
    validators: () => [Validators.required],
  });
  
  export function timeZonePropContributor(propList: FormPropList<IdentityUserDto>) {
    propList.addByIndex(timeZoneProp, 4);
  }
  
  export const identityCreateFormPropContributors: IdentityCreateFormPropContributors = {
    [eIdentityComponents.Users]: [
        timeZonePropContributor,
    ],
  };
  
  export const identityEditFormPropContributors = identityCreateFormPropContributors;
```

But this is adding the field directly on users component, so I changed:

eIdentityComponents.Users to [eAccountComponents.PersonalSettings]

But it throws the following error:

> Type '{ "Account.PersonalSettingsComponent": ((propList:
> FormPropList) => void)[]; }' is not assignable to
> type 'Partial<{ "Identity.RolesComponent":
> CreateFormPropContributorCallback[];
> "Identity.UsersComponent":
> CreateFormPropContributorCallback[]; }>'.   Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and
> '[eAccountComponents.PersonalSettings]' does not exist in type
> 'Partial<{ "Identity.RolesComponent":
> CreateFormPropContributorCallback[];
> "Identity.UsersComponent":
> CreateFormPropContributorCallback[]; }>'.

What dto should I change to import the new property and see my change? also, how can I display it as a combo box and populate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check ABP extensible form or extensible table. You can add or remove a field with its

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Data-Table-Column-Extensions